# Display radio button options horizontally in a table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

Current code:

```
 <tr>
  <td style="font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 100%;">
  Does our applying process live up to your expectations?  <br/>
    <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Strongly Agree" >Strongly Agree<br>
    <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Somewhat Agree" >Somewhat Agree <br>
    <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="XX" value="Neither Agree nor Disagree" >Neither Agree nor Disagree<br>
    <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="XX" value="Somewhat Disagree" >Somewhat Disagree<br>
    <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="XX" value="Strongly Disagree" >Strongly Disagree<br>
    <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Not Applicable" >Not Applicable <br>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

This will display the options in vertical list, I would really need to display them horizontally using inline css.

Ideally it would look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Noi.jpg

And that there can be multiple questions listed in the table, without needing to specify the answer labels for each question.

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried? It's expected that you show some effort and show us what you've tried so we can help

Comment: Hi Darren, I tried to play around with ways that were suggested in the following link, but was unable to get it working : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650344/horizontal-center-radio-button-in-table

Comment: Add what you've tried into the question - that way users can see where you might be going wrong and explain why - this can help us to learn too!

Comment: Plz check this link.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145973/how-to-align-radio-buttons-horizontally-below-labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145973/how-to-align-radio-buttons-horizontally-below-labels)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Place Radio Button Label Above Using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463785/place-radio-button-label-above-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want like this?

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td style="font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 100%;">
    Does our applying process live up to your expectations?
    <br/>
    <div>
      <p>Strongly Agree</p>
      <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Strongly Agree">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Strongly Agree</p>
      <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Strongly Agree">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Strongly Agree</p>
      <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Strongly Agree">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Strongly Agree</p>
      <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Strongly Agree">
    </div>

  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you can use <label> instead of <p>

Comment: Hi, thank you! This solution seems to work mostly. The options are now vertically.
Do you know, how can I add the question below in a table format? 

Like: http://imgur.com/a/OYOoy

Comment: @Atheri you need to add an additional <tr> for a different question below

Answer (score 1):

Using flexboxes for horizontal alignment.

Made the id for each radio button unique (0-5) and defined labels for the text.

```css
.options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.option {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 16%;
}

.option * {
  width: 100%;
}

.option label {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.option input {
  align-self: flex-end; /* aligns it at the bottom */
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td style="font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 100%;">
    Does our applying process live up to your expectations? <br/><br/>
    <div class="options">
      <div class="option">
        <label for="0">Strongly Agree</label>
        <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Strongly Agree">
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <label for="1">Somewhat Agree</label>
        <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="1" name="XX" value="Somewhat Agree">
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <label for="2">Neither Agree nor Disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="2" name="XX" value="Neither Agree nor Disagree">
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <label for="3">Somewhat Disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="3" name="XX" value="Somewhat Disagree">
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <label for="4">Strongly Disagree</label>
        <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="4" name="XX" value="Strongly Disagree">
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <label for="5">Not Applicable</label>
        <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="5" name="XX" value="Not Applicable">
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you Adding `<br>` at the end of line .. ?
Try this

`<label>Strongly Agree<br><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Strongly Agree"></label>`

OR 
Just remove `<br>`

`<input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Somewhat Agree" >Somewhat Agree`

Answer (score 0):

remove all `<br>` and write `input` between `<td></td>`

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 100%;">

      <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Strongly Agree">Strongly Agree
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Somewhat Agree">Somewhat Agree
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="XX" value="Neither Agree nor Disagree">Neither Agree nor Disagree</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="XX" value="Somewhat Disagree">Somewhat Disagree
    </td>
    <td><input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="XX" value="Strongly Disagree">Strongly Disagree</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Not Applicable">Not Applicable
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to achieve all radio button in horizontally but it is better to use label for text and its for attribute for better results.

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 100%;">
        Does our applying process live up to your expectations?  <br/>
            <div style="display:inline-block">
              <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Strongly Agree" >Strongly Agree
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline-block">
              <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Somewhat Agree" >Somewhat Agree
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline-block">
              <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="XX" value="Neither Agree nor Disagree" >Neither Agree nor Disagree
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline-block">
              <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="XX" value="Somewhat Disagree" >Somewhat Disagree
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline-block">
              <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox1" id="0" name="XX" value="Strongly Disagree" >Strongly Disagree
            </div>
            <div style="display:inline-block">
              <input type="radio" class="myCheckbox2" id="0" name="XX" value="Not Applicable" >Not Applicable
            </div>
      </td>
</tr>
```